# Inkscape: make two segments of the same path parallel or perpendicular

Tags: inkscape

Is there a command to make to make two segments of the same path parallel or perpendicular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest and most universal way to achieve that would be by using a guide line.

Drag one out of the ruler, snap its origin to the end of one of the path segments that is meant to stay in place, then hold Shift and rotate the guide, until it snaps with the other end of the segment that is fine.

Then move the guide to the second segment, and snap the node that is 'off' to the guide.

Edit: for perpendicular, double-click on the guide after it has the correct slope for the first segment, then check the 'relative' box and add 90°.

Comment: Your link is completely broken

Comment: I've removed it, no idea how to find something on imgur that doesn't seem to be there.